# Split string and get particular element

Tags: c#

In VBA the split function can be used to split a string and get a particular element in one line using

```
'Get 4th element of split directly
spElement = Split(someString,",")(3)
```

Is there a similar way of doing this in C#? I've seen examples of using LINQ Last() like this

```
spElement = someString.Split(',').Last();
```

But is it possible to get an actual element of the split array by number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a specific position in arrays using `[]` in c#

```
spElement = someString.Split(',')[3];
```

For more information, check this [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: @OP Note that this isn't in any way specific to `string.Split`.  This is how *all* arrays are accessed in C#.

Comment: Thanks for that. I feel a bit silly now as it was pretty obvious :)

Comment: And don't forget that arrays are always zero based in C#. `string[] parts = s.Split(','); string firstPart = parts[0];`